# Sending __NSCFString to NSEntityDescription's entityForName:inManagedObjectContext: returns nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsstring

In Xcode 5: (I'm using 5.1.1)

1. Create a new iPhone project, choosing the *Master-Detail Application* template with core data enabled.
2. In the *xcdatamodeld* file, you should see a default entity has been created: *Event*. Create a new entity and call it `Delta`. (Note: these names are important as you will soon see.)
3. In the `fetchedResultsController` method of *MasterViewController.m*:

Change this:

```
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Event" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
```

To this:

```
NSString *entityName = [@"E" stringByAppendingString:@"vent"];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:entityName inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
```

Now run the app on the **iPhone Retina (4-inch 64-bit)** simulator.

You will get the following error message:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'executeFetchRequest:error: A fetch request must have an entity.'

The reason is because `entityForName:inManagedObjectContext:` is returning nil.

Any idea why this is happening?

### Workaround 1: Don't use __NSCFString

If you put a breakpoint on the line right after `entityName` is set, you will see that its value and type are:

> entityName    **__NSCFString** *  @"Event"

If you change the line that assigns entityName to:

```
NSString *entityName = @"Event";
```

Then its type becomes:

> entityName    **__NSCFConstantString** *  @"Event"

and `entity` will now be populated correctly, and the app won't crash.

### Workaround 2: Make Event the top most object in the xcdatamodel

Rename `Delta` to `Foxtrot` and run the original code. The variable `entityName` is still an `__NSCFString`, but `entityForName:inManagedObjectContext:` will return a valid value this time.

### Workaround 3: Use a 32-bit device

If you change the simulator to a 32-bit device, the original code will work correctly.

Comment: Same as @duci9y, I do not get that error. I copied and pasted the code from the question, and it seems to work fine. The `entityName` variable is an `__NSCFString`.

Comment: @TomHarrington: I found another requirement in order to reproduce this, and updated the question accordingly. It must be running on the 64-bit simulator. When you tried to reproduce it did you try the 64-bit simulator by any chance?

Comment: OK I can reproduce it now-- 64 bits is key. This is extremely weird. I'm going to file a bug about it, but first: What is the real use case for this? In what situation(s) would you want to do something like this? I only ask because when I file the bug they'll probably want to know.

Comment: Also, another workaround is to add a line reading `entityName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", entityName]` after you set up the initial string value.

Comment: I tried this on the 64 bit iPad and iPhone simulators, and a 64 bit iPad, and it worked. Weird.

Comment: @duci9y: "worked" as in it "worked to reproduce the crash", or worked as in "it worked and didn't cause a crash"?

Comment: Didn't cause a crash.

Comment: @Tom: In this particular case, I was testing out different things with core data, so I had multiple versions of the same entity (with slight variations), only they were prefixed with a different letter depending on the test. For example, `AEntity`, `BEntity`, `CEntity`, etc. Depending on a flag which controlled the prefix, it would generate the string and then use that entity name with core data.

Comment: @TomHarrington: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", entityName] works for me too. Please, post it as answer so we can vote you up.